# Glassfish is running in background

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tcp, glassfish, application-server

Glassfish Server is running in background and I am not able to stop, start or restart the process. I know, restarting the system will do the job. Is there any other process to stop the process?

Here is the details:

1. When I try to stop, it says it is domain1 is not running:

   > C:\Server\glassfish4\glassfish\bin>asadmin stop-domain
   >   CLI306: Warning - The server located at C:\Server\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1 is not running.
   >   Command stop-domain executed successfully.
2. However I am able to open admin console in web browser for http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf
3. When I am trying to start or restart it throws error:

   > C:\Server\glassfish4\glassfish\bin>asadmin start-domain There is a
   >   process already using the admin port 4848 -- it probably is another
   >   instance of a GlassFish server. Command start-domain failed.
   >
   > C:\Server\glassfish4\glassfish\bin>asadmin restart-domain Server is
   >   not running, will attempt to start it... There is a process already
   >   using the admin port 4848 -- it probably is another instance of a
   >   GlassFish server. Command restart-domain failed.
4. I tried to find PID with `netstat -a -n -o` command for the port 4848. I got two entries but not localhost id:

   ```
   TCP    0.0.0.0:4848           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       9116 
   TCP    [::]:4848              [::]:0                 LISTENING       9116
   ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
taskkill /F /PID 9116
```

Also find the PIDs of processes which hold `port 8080` and kill them. (If above solution don't work)

```
netstat -aon | find "LISTENING" | find ":8080"
taskkill /F /PID process_id_here
```

Answer (score 3):

If are you using Mac OS you should open terminal and will write following:

```
jps
```

(jps - is command that help you to see PID of this process of GlassFish)
in my case I have following information:

```
MBP-Dmytro:~ melnychukdv$ jps
4004 ASMain
4500 Jps
```

After that we just kill this PID (in my case it is 4004):

```
sudo kill -4004 {PID}
```

or

```
sudo kill 4004 {PID}
```

That's all.